# How to attach gameobject without inheriting scale in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make grapple hook mechanic for my game and I have problem with attaching hook to the rope. Rope is changing its length during game by scaling up and down. Because of that when I attach the hook to the rope by hinge joint it messes up after changing the scale of the rope. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: this is a real pain in the ass.  sometimes you have to temporarily parent it to something else.  it's also worth noting:  ***you should never, ever, have anything at any scale other than 1*** !!!  "scale" is just sort of a bad feature Unity added.  ***you must make the models the correct size (in meters) to begin with, and never have to alter any scale for any reason***.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/471340/creating-a-retractable-grappling-hook.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty GameObject and add both the rope, joint and hook as child objects to it (i.e. all three should be siblings). This way, whichever part you scale won't affect the rest. To scale the whole thing, you have to scale the parent GO.
**EDIT** (for comment)
Do NOT scale the parent GameObject, but the rope only, so the hook's dimensions won't change.
For the other issue, the most simple (as of coding) solution I can think of is, to add two extra (empty) GOs: one as the *parent* of the rope, and place it to the end of it where the hook belongs to. The other as the *parent* of the hook, place it to the end of it (to the part which should attach to the rope) and after rope resize/scale, move the two GOs on top of each other

Comment: This doesn't work for me because when i scale one object the hook changes its position relative to the end of the rope, and when i scale GO the hook is also scaled(I don't want it).